# Mysqli error on function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to update a function to work with mysqli instead of mysql. The function is for generating unique download keys. I keep getting the error: Fatal Error: Call to a member function query() on a non- object on line 20.
I can't figure out what I have got wrong and hope someone can show me. Thanks.

```
<?php

$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'xxx';
$dbPassword = 'xxx';
$dbName = 'xxx';


//Connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);


//error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



function createKey(){
    //create a random key
    $strKey = md5(microtime());

    //check to make sure this key isnt already in use
    $resCheck = "SELECT count(*) FROM downloads WHERE downloadkey = '{$strKey}' LIMIT 1";
    $arrCheck = $db->query($resCheck);
    if($arrCheck['count(*)']){
        //key already in use
        return createKey();
    }else{
        //key is OK
        return $strKey;
    }
}

//get a unique download key
$strKey = createKey();

//insert the download record into the database

$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', 'onetimedownload.zip', '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')");


?>
```

Comment: Change `$strKey = createKey();` to `$strKey = createKey($db);` and receive `$db` in your function. Or make `$db` as global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with PHP variable scoping. Add **global $db** inside createKey() function before you refer to the $db variable:

```
  function createKey(){

        global $db; // Add this line

        //create a random key
        $strKey = md5(microtime());

        //check to make sure this key isnt already in use
        $resCheck = "SELECT count(*) FROM downloads WHERE downloadkey = '{$strKey}' LIMIT 1";
        $arrCheck = $db->query($resCheck);
        if($arrCheck['count(*)']){
            //key already in use
            return createKey();
        }else{
            //key is OK
            return $strKey;
        }
    }
```

Learn more about variable scoping here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Using global is very very bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Pass the $db variable as a parameter in the function createKey or use as a global variable.  Personally I prefer to pass it as a parameter.
The issue is that the db variable does not exist in your instance.  Hence the reason why you should pass it as a parameter

```
function createKey($db) { // code goes here.. }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `$db` as parameter as it is not awailable in function scope

```
function createKey($db){
    //create a random key
    $strKey = md5(microtime());

    //check to make sure this key isnt already in use
    $resCheck = "SELECT count(*) FROM downloads WHERE downloadkey = '{$strKey}' LIMIT 1";
    $arrCheck = $db->query($resCheck);
    if($arrCheck['count(*)']){
        //key already in use
        return createKey();
    }else{
        //key is OK
        return $strKey;
    }
}

//get a unique download key
$strKey = createKey($db);
```